# Where to place testing helpers in angular CLI project

Tags: angular

We have an Angular CLI project. We have our `spec.ts` files in various locations, tested via Karma with nothing specific.

We want to use, as described in the official Angular doc, some helper classes to help us test various things across application. For example, the official doc place, in a `testing/index.ts` file, a function to simulate click handling. It's then usable in all tests.

The problem is the project in the doc uses SystemJS and I'd like to reuse these helpers in the Angular CLI project structure.

**Is there any way, in Angular CLI project structure, to make this kind of file loaded and their function made available in our `spec.ts` files?**

Karma.conf mention the `src/test.ts` file but I don't know if it can be a proper place for these stubs and helper functions.

### File examples

Here are files from the doc and the karma.conf.js produced by Angular CLI.

#### Angular.io doc `testing/index.ts` file:

```js
import { DebugElement }           from '@angular/core';
import { tick, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';

export * from './jasmine-matchers';
export * from './router-stubs';

///// Short utilities /////

/** Wait a tick, then detect changes */
export function advance(f: ComponentFixture<any>): void {
  tick();
  f.detectChanges();
}

/**
 * Create custom DOM event the old fashioned way
 *
 * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent
 * Although officially deprecated, some browsers (phantom) don't accept the preferred "new Event(eventName)"
 */
export function newEvent(eventName: string, bubbles = false, cancelable = false) {
  let evt = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');  // MUST be 'CustomEvent'
  evt.initCustomEvent(eventName, bubbles, cancelable, null);
  return evt;
}

// See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button
/** Button events to pass to `DebugElement.triggerEventHandler` for RouterLink event handler */
export const ButtonClickEvents = {
   left:  { button: 0 },
   right: { button: 2 }
};

/** Simulate element click. Defaults to mouse left-button click event. */
export function click(el: DebugElement | HTMLElement, eventObj: any = ButtonClickEvents.left): void {
  if (el instanceof HTMLElement) {
    el.click();
  } else {
    el.triggerEventHandler('click', eventObj);
  }
}
```

#### `testing/router-stubs.ts` file:

```js
 // export for convenience.
export { ActivatedRoute, Router, RouterLink, RouterOutlet} from '@angular/router';

import { Component, Directive, Injectable, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';

@Directive({
  selector: '[routerLink]',
  host: {
    '(click)': 'onClick()'
  }
})
export class RouterLinkStubDirective {
  @Input('routerLink') linkParams: any;
  navigatedTo: any = null;

  onClick() {
    this.navigatedTo = this.linkParams;
  }
}

@Component({selector: 'router-outlet', template: ''})
export class RouterOutletStubComponent { }

@Injectable()
export class RouterStub {
  navigate(commands: any[], extras?: NavigationExtras) { }
}


// Only implements params and part of snapshot.params
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class ActivatedRouteStub {

  // ActivatedRoute.params is Observable
  private subject = new BehaviorSubject(this.testParams);
  params = this.subject.asObservable();

  // Test parameters
  private _testParams: {};
  get testParams() { return this._testParams; }
  set testParams(params: {}) {
    this._testParams = params;
    this.subject.next(params);
  }

  // ActivatedRoute.snapshot.params
  get snapshot() {
    return { params: this.testParams };
  }
}
```

#### Angular CLI `karma.conf.js` file

```js
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
              ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul']
              : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add import statements in your test.ts referencing your testing/*.ts files.

I have one file called testing/index.ts and this is how I import it in my test.ts

`import { } from './testing';`

Comment: Could you expand on this a little? What would I import in test.ts and how/why would I use that in a .spec.ts file?